# Merging multiple rows with multiple factors to create a new row in a dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new row in my data set that sums values of multiple rows.  My original dataset is a bit cumbersome and looks like this:

```
TranID PT  VegType  Int1 Int2 Int3 Int4 Int5 Int6 Int7 Int8 Int9 Int10 
   1   1M  Shrub      0    0    0    0    5    7    0    0    0    0    
   1   1M  Sapling    1    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    5    0 
   1   1M  Vine       0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0 
   1   1M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   1M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   2M  Shrub      0    0    0    0    5    7    0    0    0    0    
   1   2M  Sapling    1    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    5    0 
   1   2M  Vine       0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0 
   1   2M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   2M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   3M  Shrub      0    0    0    0    5    7    0    0    0    0    
   1   3M  Sapling    1    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    5    0 
   1   3M  Vine       0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0 
   1   3M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   3M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   4M  Shrub      0    0    0    0    5    7    0    0    0    0    
   1   4M  Sapling    1    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    5    0 
   1   4M  Vine       0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0 
   1   4M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   4M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   5M  Shrub      0    0    0    0    5    7    0    0    0    0    
   1   5M  Sapling    1    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    5    0 
   1   5M  Vine       0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0 
   1   5M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   1   5M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

The first column heading is transect ID, and along each transect are 5 1-meter interval points where we recorded the number of stems present within 10 height intervals (the Int column heading).  I'm interested in reducing the 1st 3 veg types (Shrub, Sapling, and Vine) by summing their values into a single row named "WoodyVeg."  There are several hundred transects, and I would like to have this new row created for each PT within a transect:

```
A   1M  WoodyVeg   1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5    0
A   1M  Grass      1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
A   1M  Forb       0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I tried using the aggregate function but could not produce the correct result.  I think I'm getting thrown off by having 2 different factors (TranID and PT).  Is there a way to do this with aggregate, or another function/R package?

Comment: You can use `aggregate()` but you need to create a proper list. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer uses `aggregate()` and does not require any other package.

Replace df by your data frame name.

> ```
> df$VegType <- factor(df$VegType)
> levels(df$VegType) <- list(WoodyVeg=c("Shrub", "Sapling", "Vine"), Forb=c("Forb"),Grass=c("Grass"))
> df1<-aggregate(df[,4:13],by=list(df$TranID,df$PT,df$VegType),FUN=sum)
> names(df1)<-names(df)
> df1[with(df1, order(df1$PT)),]
> ```

```
   TranID PT  VegType Int1 Int2 Int3 Int4 Int5 Int6 Int7 Int8 Int9 Int10
       1 1M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
       1 1M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 1M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 2M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
       1 2M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 2M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 3M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
       1 3M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 3M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 4M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
       1 4M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 4M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 5M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
       1 5M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
       1 5M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 = setDT(df)[,as.list(c(VegType='WoodyVeg', 
                         colSums(.SD[!VegType %in% c('Grass','Forb'), -1, with=F])))
                ,.(TranID, PT)]

dt2 = setDT(df)[, .SD[VegType %in% c('Grass','Forb')], .(TranID, PT)]

rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))

#    TranID PT  VegType Int1 Int2 Int3 Int4 Int5 Int6 Int7 Int8 Int9 Int10
# 1:      1 1M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
# 2:      1 2M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
# 3:      1 3M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
# 4:      1 4M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
# 5:      1 5M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
# 6:      1 1M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 7:      1 1M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 8:      1 2M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# 9:      1 2M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#10:      1 3M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#11:      1 3M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#12:      1 4M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#13:      1 4M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#14:      1 5M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#15:      1 5M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: the .(TranID, PT) in dt2 doesn't seem to do anything? why not simplify to : dtx = setDT(df)[VegType %in% c("Grass", "Forb")]; 
all.equal(dtx, dt2) # TRUE

Comment: `colSums` is discouraged with data.table. Maybe you want `lapply(..., sum)`? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#5-dont-use-colsums-use-lapply-on-sd

Comment: Ack, too late to edit my comment, but from the same page: avoid coercing with `as.list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(VegCategory = 
           ifelse(VegType %in% c("Shrub", "Sapling", "Vine"),
                  "WoodyVeg",
                  VegType) ) %>%
  group_by(TranID, PT, VegCategory) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Comment: I saw in your suggested edit that you were having difficulty with numbers ending up in VegCategory. I would suggest you begin your code with options(stringsAsFactors) = FALSE

Comment: Also, you can overwrite VegType if you want, but you would lose access to the original data. I tend to write code with the idea of immutable columns in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Mimicking @bramtayl's dplyr approach...

```
library(data.table)
DT[, copy(.SD)[1:3, VegType := "WoodyVeg"][, lapply(.SD,sum), by=VegType], by=.(TranID,PT)]
```

which gives

```
    TranID PT  VegType Int1 Int2 Int3 Int4 Int5 Int6 Int7 Int8 Int9 Int10
 1:      1 1M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
 2:      1 1M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 3:      1 1M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 4:      1 2M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
 5:      1 2M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 6:      1 2M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 7:      1 3M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
 8:      1 3M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 9:      1 3M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
10:      1 4M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
11:      1 4M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
12:      1 4M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
13:      1 5M WoodyVeg    1    0    2    1    6    9    0    0    5     0
14:      1 5M    Grass    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
15:      1 5M     Forb    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Or, a rehash of the Colonel's data.table answer without the [discouraged `as.list` and `colSums`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts):

```
DT[, rbind( 
    .SD[1:3, c( list(VegType="WoodyVeg"), lapply(.SD,sum) ), .SDcols=!"VegType"], 
    .SD[-(1:3)]
), by=.(TranID,PT)]
```